# Why i can't use <cliprect> in android anim resource just like activity_open_enter.xml from API 28

Tags: android, android-studio

I like the transition between activities from android Pie, so i wanted to import it to my own application, but coping the file: **activity_open_enter.xml** from **\Sdk\platforms\android-28\data\res\anim** resulted in a error in my IDE:

```
Element <cliprect is not allowed here.
```

.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="4.1%"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:duration="425"/>
<cliprect
    android:fromLeft="0%"
    android:fromTop="95.9%"
    android:fromRight="100%"
    android:fromBottom="100%"
    android:toLeft="0%"
    android:toTop="0%"
    android:toRight="100%"
    android:toBottom="100%"
    android:interpolator="@interpolator/fast_out_extra_slow_in"
    android:duration="425"/>
```

My minimum api is 21, and my target is 28

Answer (score 0):

This is a private component from Android, and cannot be used.